# Have a list break to a new column at a set interval

Tags: php, javascript, css

I have lists generated from php that are varying lengths.  How could I have the list at a certain height break and start filling a new column rather than remain in one long column?

If lists are no good I would be fine doing it with divs but I can not figure out how to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at column-* declarations in CSS3. Be aware that they most likely won't work in IE as Firefox/Webkit browsers require hacks for it to work.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

You would then just set a height to the wrapping div, which is where it will cut off and start a new column. I can't think of a way to do this after a set number of items, unless you add logic in your PHP to start a new column `<div>`/`<ul>` after X elements. Would even be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks yes unfortunately the site needs to support IE.  The php solution is what I am after.  I just did a lousy job of wording my question.

Comment: Yeah I would suggest doing this with just PHP and then doing logic to separate them into columns.

Answer (score 0):

If order isn't important, you can simulate columns by giving each `li` a fixed width and simply make them wrap around (`float: left` ought to do it).

Otherwise, you'll have to wait for CSS3 to be finalized and adopted.

Comment: That will just stack them horizontally before they wrap to the next line no?  I need them vertical until certain height and then continue at the next column, I am thinking it needs a php or javascript solution.

Comment: That's why I said it only "simulates" columns. It won't work in all cases, but it may be preferable to requiring JavaScript, and it will retain the semantic structure of the list, unlike using multiple lists.